# How to install typehead.js without bower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am unfamiliar of how to install a new javascript file. I am trying to install typeahead.js. THe instructions suggested using bower for installation. However, bower is now deprecated. How would one install the .js file without bower. There are some links such as below that suggest editing the file. Is there a simple way through npm?

Without the proper install, I am getting the following error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Bloodhound is not defined ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined
```

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1211

Thanks,

Howard

Comment: in the getting startet section you can find a zip file with the required files: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js you just need to include the files in your html file

Comment: Download the script file? https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js

Comment: Do I have edit the jquery file?  Because the error is saying that jquery does not recognize typeahead.js or bloodhound.js

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, there are multiple ways of installing `typeahead.js`.

### Here are some:

- Download from the [GitHub releases](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/releases)
- Using a CDN:

  - UNPKG: `https://unpkg.com/typeahead.js`
  - CDNJS: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js`
- Via NPM: `npm install typeahead.js`
- Via Yarn: `yarn add typeahead.js`

There are other solutions, but I can't cite them all, you'll understand .

I hope I helped you .